# Parent class holds a static instance of child class C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am declaring two classes like the following, A is the parent class, B subclass A:

```
//a.h
#include "b.h"
//class B;     Adding this line doesn't work
class A{
    static B b;
}

//b.h
#include "a.h"
class B:public A{     // XCode error here: expected class name

}
```

However, XCode 6.1 don't let me compile and keeps saying "expected class name".

In fact, I am trying to implement a state machine mentioned in the book Game Programming Patterns http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html#static-states . In that book, the parent state class holds static instances of the child classes.

Comment: Your design needs deodorant.

Comment: The forward declaration `class B;` is fine. The circular includes, not. Scrape `#include "b.h"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code would suffice for you :-

```
//b.h
#include "a.h"     <<<< This requires full definition for `A`.
class B : public A
{ 

}

//a.h         <<<<< No need to include any file.
class B;
class A{
    static B b;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding an include file has become a second nature to me.